# Cache blocking brings no improvement for image filter on ARM

Tags: caching, arm, cortex-a

I'm experimenting with cache blocking. To do that, I implemented 2 convolution based smoothing algorithms. The gaussian kernel I'm using looks like this:

[image]

The first algorithm is just the simple double for loop, looping from left to right, top to bottom as shown below.

[image]

Image source: (https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/efg/521/f02/common/lectures/notes/lec9.html)

In the second algorithm I tried to play with cache blocking by spliting the loops into chunks, which became something like the following. I used a BLOCK size of 512x512.

[image]

Image source: (https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/efg/521/f02/common/lectures/notes/lec9.html)

I'm running the code on a raspberry pi 3B+, which has a Cortex-A53 with 32KB of L1 and 256KB of L2, I believe. I ran the two algorithms with different image sizes (2048x1536, 6000x4000, 12000x8000, 16000x12000. 8bit gray scale images). But across different image sizes, I saw the run time being very similar.

**The question is** shouldn't the first algorithm experience access latency which the second should not, especially when using large size image (like 12000x8000). Base on the description of cache blocking in this [link](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/cache-blocking-techniques.html), when processing data at the end of image rows using the 1st algorithm, the data at the beginning of the rows should have been evicted from the L1 cache. Using 12000x8000 size image as an example, since we are using 5x5 kernel, 5 rows of data is need, which is 12000x5=60KB, already larger than the 32KB L1 size. When we start processing data for a new row, 4 rows of previous data are still needed but they are likely gone in L1 so needs to be re-fetched. But for the second algorithm it shouldn't have this problem because the block size is small. Can anyone please tell me what am I missing?

I also profiled the algorithm using [oprofile](https://oprofile.sourceforge.io/docs/armv7-ca5-events.php) with the following data:

### Algorithm 1

| event | count |
| --- | --- |
| L1D_CACHE_REFILL | 13,933,254 |
| PREFETCH_LINEFILL | 13,281,559 |

### Algorithm 2

| event | count |
| --- | --- |
| L1D_CACHE_REFILL | 9,456,369 |
| PREFETCH_LINEFILL | 8,725,250 |

So it looks like the 1st algorithm does have more cache miss compared to the second, reflecting by the L1D_CACHE_REFILL counts. But it also has higher data prefetching rate, which maybe due to the simple behavior of the loop. So is the whole story of cache blocking not taking into account data prefetching?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you're right blocking will reduce cache misses by keeping the input window in cache.

I suspect the main reason you're not seeing a speedup is because the cache is prefetching from all 5 input rows. Your performance counters show more prefetch loads in the unblocked implementation. I suspect many textbook examples are out of date since cache prefetching has kept getting better.  Intel's L2 cache can detect and prefetch from up to 16 linear streams about 10 years ago, I think.

Assume the filter takes 5 * 5 cycles. So that would be 20.8 ns = 25 / 1.2GHz on RPI3. The IO cost will be reading a 5 high column of new input pixels. The amortized IO cost will be 5 bytes / 20.8ns = 229 MiB/s, which is much less than the ~2 GiB/s DRAM bandwidth. So in theory, the relatively slow computation combined with prefetching (I'm not certain how effective) means that memory access isn't a bottleneck.

Try increasing the filter height. The cache can only detect and prefetch from a certain # streams. Or try vectorizing the computation so that memory access becomes the bottleneck.